# Align TextField and Text in ReactNative?

Tags: react-native, material-ui

I'm trying to align my component `TextInput` that uses a `TextField` from [`@ubaids/react-native-material-textfield`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ubaids/react-native-material-textfield) and a `Text` but i couldn’t. The result i have is in the image below :

[image: result]

I added `alignItems: 'center'` in the container but i didn't work. My code is:

```js
<View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.input}>
              <TextInput
                containerStyle={{ height: 20, marginVertical: 10 }}
                label=""
                value=""
                keyboardType="phone-pad"
              />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.label}>
              <Text style={[styles.text, { textTransform: 'uppercase' }]}>Text</Text>
            </View>
</View>
```

```css
container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
 input: {
    flex: 0.2
  },
label: {
    paddingTop: 20,
    paddingHorizontal: 10
  },
```

Comment: why you add `styles.label` to the container view and the `Text` component at same time?

Comment: it was just a mistake i changed it.

Answer (score 0):

You should try and add justifyContent to your container‘s Styling:

container: {
flexDirection: 'row',
alignItems: 'center',
justifyContent: 'center'
}

And also, you don't need the view above the Text with the styles.label.

This way, both your TextInput and your Text components will be aligned on both axis

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `display` css property to `inline-block` for both `input` and `label` style:

```
  text: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: "1.5rem",
    marginVertical: "1em",
  },
  container: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  input: {
    flex: 0.2,
    display: 'inline-block'
  },
  label: {
   // paddingTop: 20,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    display: 'inline-block'
  }
```

As you can see I commented `paddingTop: 20` in `label` (but if you need, you can add it again but you have to add it to `input` also).

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-validated-textinput-forked-ur8ph?file=/src/App.js) a codesandbox.

Answer (score 0):

Already answered but I'd like to add a bit more on the topic and different ways to do it depending on your use case.

You can add adjustsFontSizeToFit={true} (currently undocumented) to Text Component to auto adjust the size inside a parent node.

```html
 <Text adjustsFontSizeToFit={true} numberOfLines={1}>Hiiiz</Text>
```

You can also add the following in your Text Component:

```html
<Text style={{textAlignVertical: "center",textAlign: "center",}}>Hiiiz</Text>
```